# Testing Backward Compatibility issues while Upgrading from Jquery 1.11.0 and Jquery UI 1.10.4 to Jquery 3.x and Jquery UI 1.12.x

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

We have multiple sites running on Jquery 1.11.0 and Jquery UI 1.10.4. To fix the vulnerability issues reported by Chrome Developer Audit report, we want to upgrade to the latest stable versions. As suggested by Audit report these are  Jquery 3.x and Jquery UI 1.12.x.

Is there any safe way we can upgrade Jquery and Jquery UI also check for back compatibility, so that it will not break any existing UI.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest answer is no, you would need to test it out on a test server to detect and eliminate any side effects/bugs.

However that said, jQuery has had good backward compatibility. I have been using it for more than a few years now through its many releases of the core and have not had any breaking issues.
jQuery has been proactive with backward compatibility that they actually produce a backward compatibility plugin for each release.

Here's a reference for an upgrade guide to Jquery 3.x. Ref [Upgrade Guide to Jquery 3.x](https://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/3.0/)

Comment: "Breaking changes" are always a problem.